# OmniThread: How to pass a TRect in SetParameter?

Tags: delphi, parallel-processing, delphi-xe2, omnithreadlibrary

In a program using the OmniThread library, how can I pass a TRect in SetParameter? Example:

```
procedure TestParameters(const ATask: IOmniTask);
begin
  // how can I access the TRect here?
end;

FTestTask := CreateTask(TestParameters, 'TestParameters')
               .MonitorWith(OTLMonitor)
               .SetParameter('FormRect', Self.ClientRect) // does not work
               .Run;
```

Is there a general rule how to use different types in SetParameter?

Comment: Use anon method and variable capture

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Can you give me a code example? If you write an answer with a code example that works, I'll accept it as solution.

Comment: I cannot right now. There are lots in the OTL docs and examples.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `TOmniValue.FromRecord<T>` and `TOmniValue.ToRecord<T>`.

```
procedure TestParameters(const ATask: IOmniTask);
var
  formRect: TRect;
begin
  formRect := ATask.Param['FormRect'].ToRecord<TRect>;
end;

FTestTask := CreateTask(TestParameters, 'TestParameters')
               .MonitorWith(OTLMonitor)
               .SetParameter('FormRect', TOmniValue.FromRecord<TRect>(ClientRect))
               .Run;
```